# How to know when a Live Streaming has ended in MPEG DASH?

Tags: algorithm, live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I'm doing a player for MPEG DASH and, after reading the [ISO](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c065274_ISO_IEC_23009-1_2014.zip), I'm not sure how to know if the Live Streaming ended?

So far, I build the URL based on the BaseURLs with the (`SegmentTemplate` + `Representation`) combination and, I can do the download of the segments from the `SegmentTimeline` but, there is an easy attribute to check for:

- Know how often should I update the MPD
- Know what attribute/formula should I validate in order to stop streaming?

Is not like I can download until it breaks. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a section in the [DASH-IF Interoperability Points](https://dashif-documents.azurewebsites.net/DASH-IF-IOP/master/DASH-IF-IOP.html#timing-mpd-updates-theend) document:

> 5.2.9.5.3. End of live content
>
> Live services can reach a point where no more content will be produced
>   - existing content will be played back by clients and once they reach the end, playback will cease.
>
> This document requires:
>
> - When this occurs, services SHALL define a fixed duration for the last
>     period, remove the **MPD@minimumUpdatePeriod** attribute and cease
>     performing MPD updates to signal that no more content will be added to
>     the MPD.
> - The **MPD@type** MAY be changed to **static** at this point or later
>     if the service is to be converted to a static MPD for on-demand
>     viewing.

See also the discussion [here](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/DASH-IF-IOP/issues/213).